# Focus selector, keep focus on popup

Tags: html, css

Morning, I have an issue with the styling of a popup window I am trying to create, when a button is clicked, the popup is shown and keeps focus when clicking on the popup body, although when clicking a child element of the popup within it, the popup loses focus.

How can I keep focus on the popup when clicking any child element within the popup?

Many Thanks.

```
     <html>
       <head>

<style type="text/css">
#modal{display:none;}
#modal:focus {display:block;}
#modal:focus * #modal{display:block;}/*i thought maybe this would apply when any child element of #modal has          focus, although if i give a child element of modal a tabindex, it still doesn't work.*/
.num:focus + #modal{display:block;}
 </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="onetwo">
 <input type="button" id="btn1" class="num" tabindex="1" value="Click here"/>
<div id="modal" style="background-color:green;width:200px;height:200px;
position:absolute;top:40%;left:40%;" tabindex="2">
<input type="button" id="btn1" onclick="alert("Alerted")" value="Click.."/>
<input type="text" id="txt1" placeholder="some text"/>
</div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that as soon as you click on a child element in the popup, your button is no longer in focus and the popup will not be displayed.

This cannot be done easily just in CSS. The best way would be to use javascript and add click handlers to your button to show and hide the popup using CSS:

```
var btn = document.getElementById('btn1');

btn.onclick = function() {
    var popup = document.getElementById('modal');

    if(popup.style.display == 'block') {
        popup.style.display = 'none';
    }
    else {
        popup.style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

[See this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x7ZrJ/)